# Problem with ASP Repeater and SQL Data Source

Tags: sql-server-2005, repeater, sqldatasource

Here's my data table in my SQL DB, and below that is the code for my Repeater control:

```
ArticleID int NOT NULL,
ArticleTitle varchar(100) NOT NULL,
ArticleCategory int NOT NULL,
ArticleDate datetime NOT NULL,
ArticleContent text NOT NULL,
DeletedYN char(3) NOT NULL

<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptArticles" DataSourceID="dsLatestArticles">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <span class="title"><%#Container.DataItem("ArticleTitle")%></span><br />
        <span class="title3">Posted On: <%#Container.DataItem("ArticleDate")%></span>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate><p><%#Container.DataItem("ArticleContent")%></p></ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        <p class="RightAlign"><a href="/Articles/Read.aspx?i=<%#Container.DataItem("ArticleID") %>">Read more...</a></p>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

When I try to load the page this is on, I get an error saying `Object variable or With block variable not set.`

For reference, my SqlDataSource is configured as follows:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsLatestArticles" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:VBSiteConnectionString %>"        
    SelectCommand="SELECT [ArticleID], [ArticleTitle], [ArticleDate], [ArticleContent] FROM [Articles] WHERE ([DeletedYN] = @DeletedYN)">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="No" Name="DeletedYN" Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I don't know what I've done wrong here, can anyone see a problem?
For further reference, here's my Stack Trace:

```
[NullReferenceException: Object variable or With block variable not set.]
   Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Container..ctor(Object Instance) +510276
   Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.NewLateBinding.InternalLateIndexGet(Object Instance, Object[] Arguments, String[] ArgumentNames, Boolean ReportErrors, ResolutionFailure& Failure) +88
   Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.NewLateBinding.LateIndexGet(Object Instance, Object[] Arguments, String[] ArgumentNames) +21
   ASP.default_aspx.__DataBind__control3(Object sender, EventArgs e) in D:\Development\Projects\Web\LogansArchive\Default.aspx:9
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnDataBinding(EventArgs e) +99
   System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind(Boolean raiseOnDataBinding) +92
   System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind() +15
   System.Web.UI.Control.DataBindChildren() +211
   System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind(Boolean raiseOnDataBinding) +102
   System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind() +15
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeater.CreateItem(Int32 itemIndex, ListItemType itemType, Boolean dataBind, Object dataItem) +124
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeater.CreateControlHierarchy(Boolean useDataSource) +323
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeater.OnDataBinding(EventArgs e) +51
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeater.DataBind() +75
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeater.EnsureDataBound() +55
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeater.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) +15
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +80
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +171
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +171
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +171
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +171
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +842
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone else comes across this problem, here's a solution that I've found

**The Cause**
I was pulling data from my SqlDataSource in the `<HeaderTemplate>` section of my Repeater control.
This is what caused the problem. I'm not sure why, but the point is that doing this will not work.

**The Solution**
All data retrieval (i.e. `<%#Container.DataItem("Field1") %>` block) **must** be used in the `<ItemTemplate>` section of the Repeater control.